# Get mean and mode of dataframe depending on each column type

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if something similar has been asked before, I searched around but couldn't figure out a solution.

My dataset looks like such

```
data1 = {'Group':['Winner','Winner','Winner','Winner','Loser','Loser'],
        'Study': ['Read','Read','Notes','Cheat','Read','Read'],
        'Score': [1,.90,.80,.70,1,.90]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
```

[image]

This dataframe spans for dozens of rows, and have a set of numeric columns, and a set of string columns.
I would like to condense this into 1 row, where each entry is just the mean or mode of the column. If the column is numeric, take the mean, otherwise, take the mode. In my actual use case, the order of numeric and object columns are random, so I hope to use an iterative loop that checks for each column which action to take.

I tried this but it didn't work, it seems to be taking the entire Series as the mode.

```
for i in df1:
    if df1[i].dtype == 'float64':
        df1[i] = df1[i].mean()
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `describe` with `'all'` which calculates statistics depending upon the `dtype`. It determines the `top` (mode) for object  and `mean` for numeric columns. Then combine.

```
s = df1.describe(include='all')
s = s.loc['top'].combine_first(s.loc['mean'])

#Group      Winner
#Study        Read
#Score    0.883333
#Name: top, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ding-ding... top scores for cleverness.

Comment: `df1.mean().combine_first(df1.mode().iloc[0])`

Answer (score 3):

#### `np.number` and `select_dtypes`

```
s = df1.select_dtypes(np.number).mean()
df1.drop(s.index, axis=1).mode().iloc[0].append(s)

Group      Winner
Study        Read
Score    0.883333
dtype: object
```

Variant

```
g = df1.dtypes.map(lambda x: np.issubdtype(x, np.number))
d = {k: d for k, d in df1.groupby(g, axis=1)}
pd.concat([d[False].mode().iloc[0], d[True].mean()])

Group      Winner
Study        Read
Score    0.883333
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight variation on your solution that gets the job done

```
res = {}
for col_name, col_type in zip(df1.columns, df1.dtypes):
    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(col_type):
        res[col_name] = df1[col_name].mean()
    else:
        res[col_name]= df1[col_name].mode()[0]

pd.DataFrame(res, index = [0])
```

returns

```
    Group   Study   Score
0   Winner  Read    0.883333
```

there could be multiple `mode`s in a Series -- this solution picks the first one